# How to create custom tableview cell with three buttons having background image and tagID.I want to return tag ID when button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am creating an iPad Application in which I had created a custom table view which return rows according to the number of items in the API. Each row contains three button with background image and tagID. The purpose of tag ID is detect which button is clicked and fire an event on that click but unfortunately this is not happening like this.

My Code is as follows :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil)
{
    if (tableView==tableviewDetailLibrary)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else if (tableView==tableviewMainLibrary)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_highlighted.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
    }                
}    
if (tableView==tableviewDetailLibrary) {       
    int i1=0;        
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"i3 value is : %d", i);
        int yy = 190 *i;// For Cell Height
        for (int j=0;j<3; j++)
        {
            NSLog(@"ArrayCategories is : %d", [arrayCategories count]);
            if (arrayIndex<[arrayCategories count])
            {
                CGRect rectTitle =CGRectMake(50+135*j, yy, 100, 40);
                UILabel *lblTitle =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectTitle];
                lblTitle.text=[bookName objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];
                lblTitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(50+135*j,yy+40 , 100, 150);// Adjust Cell width here 110
                UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
                [button setFrame:rect];
                button.tag=arrayIndex+1;
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayCategories objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]]];                    
                if (imageData)
                {
                    UIImage *buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
                    NSLog(@" Button tag with image is : %d",button.tag);
                }
                else
                {
                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
                     NSLog(@" Button tag without image is : %d",button.tag);
                }

                    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];                    
                    [button release];
                    arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        i1++;
    }

}
if (tableView==tableviewMainLibrary) {
    cell.textLabel.text=[arrayLibrayMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255 green:208.0f/255 blue:255.0f/255 alpha:1.0];
    cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_highlighted.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22];
}
return cell;
}
```

Please suggest me a way how to get the tag ID when a particular button is clicked.
The above code is working fine.Here is the screen short of my simulator.Whenever I clicked on a button(image) the whole row is selected which I don't want.I want only that button tag which is tapped. ![enter image description here][1]

I'm already using [-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)btn] method which I don't write previously but now I think it should be there

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)btn {
int tagId = btn.tag;
NSLog(@"Book is:  %d",tagId);
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://miprojects.com.php5-16.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/projects/evendor/api/download/index/apicall/Bookdownload/bookid/%d/apikey/998905797b8646fd44134910d1f88c33", tagId];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
NSLog(@"URL IS :%@",url);

urlArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[urlArray addObject:url];
NSLog(@"URL Array %@",urlArray);

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[urlArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSLog(@"request : %@",request);
[request setUserInfo:dictionary];
    NSLog(@"dictionary : %@",dictionary);
[downloadTableViewObj setDownloadDirectory:fileDestination];
[downloadTableViewObj addDownloadRequest:request];    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.tag = indexPath.row + j;
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    int iTag = [sender tag];
}
```

set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` if you don't want to select the entire `cell`.

Comment: Actually arrayIndex is a variable whose initial value is 0 and with each inner loop I am incrementing its value by 1.There is no option like tagID

Comment: You mentioned in your question that, you set tagId to each button. So I told that replace that code.

Comment: Why you didn't set the bookid as tagid, bcz you passed bookid to the URL. So bookid & tagid must match otherwise your url path is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Girish, now it is going to above method but problem is not solved yet i.e. for the first row all three buttons are having tag 1,2&3 respectively(working fine) but from 2nd row onwards all buttons has same tag ID i.e. 16. Total items are 17. I think logic is breaking some where.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29893/discussion-between-sumit-sharma-and-girish)

Answer (score 0):

You can get button tag using this code..

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      //Set tag with.
      button.tag=indexPath.row + j;
```

and get that button.

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender
        int iTag=btn.tag;
    }
```